# How to create an account on a private network?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-sdk

I have already started a stellar private network. I need to generate an account on a stellar private network. I have a **secret key** and **private key** also. But I have a question about what should I enter as Sourcekey in  `Stellar.Keypair.fromSecret("******************");`?

is it **NODE_SEED** which I entered in `stellar-core.cfg` ?

```
    try{
      const pk = req.body.name;
      if(pk){
          // faucet is our root account. Make sure you replace this value with your key
          let sourceKeys = Stellar.Keypair.fromSecret("******************");
          // loading root account

          server.loadAccount(sourceKeys.publicKey())

          .then(function(sourceAccount) {
              let txn = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount)
                          .addOperation(
                              Stellar.Operation.createAccount({
                              destination: pk,
                              startingBalance: "1000"}))
                          .addMemo(Stellar.Memo.text('Test Transaction'))
                          .build();
              txn.sign(sourceKeys);

              return server.submitTransaction(txn);
              })
          .then(function(result) {
              res.send("")
          })
          .catch(function(error) {

          });
      }else{
     }
   }
   catch(err){
   }
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

`let sourceKeys = Stellar.Keypair.master();`